# Different address after struct initialization

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm looking at this simple struct:

```
struct Journal
{
  std::string title;
  std::vector<std::string> entries;

  explicit Journal (const std::string& title): title(title)
  {
    std::cout << "Address of title is " << &title << std::endl;
  }

  void add(const std::string& entry)
  {
    std::cout << "Address of title is " << &title << std::endl;
    entries.push_back(entry);
  }
};

int main() {
  std::string title = "Hello";
  std::string entry = "World";

  std::cout << "Address of title is " << &title << std::endl;
  Journal *journal = new Journal(title);

  (*journal).add(entry);
  std::cout << journal->entries.front() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I always thought the address of title should be the same through the whole execution, however, I was wrong as I got the following output:

```
Address of title is 0x7ffee90d3978
Address of title is 0x7ffee90d3978
Address of title is 0x7fa86f402740
World
```

Can somebody explain what happened after the initialization? Why would I get a different address? Does that mean a copy happened?

Comment: You are printing different address (not of `title` but `entry `) inside the function `add`. Hence the third address is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct Journal
{
  std::string title;
```

This `title` is different from the `title` you have in main(), so the addresses will be different.

```
explicit Journal (const std::string& title): title(title)
{
std::cout << "Address of title is " << &title << std::endl;
```

Here you printed the address of the `title` parameter not the member `title`, so it is the same as in `main()`. The member `title` has different address which you see when you call `add()`

Comment: You can also print the address of the member using `&(this->title)`.

Comment: @GauravSehgal Oh... I get it now, I'm really a noob in C++, so please let me ask one more question, what's the difference between using `const std::string& title` and `const std::string title`? Because `new Journal(title)` works for both.

Comment: @kevguy with `&` it references the variable in `main` that you pass in, without `&` it copies the variable's value into a new variable.

Comment: @immibis But shouldn't I use `new Journal(&title)` instead for `const std::string& title`?

Comment: @kevguy no, you're thinking of pointers (`const std::string* title`)

Comment: @immibis Oh yes, I get it now. Thank you so much!